node module error when running app with supervisord
I have a node app running under supervisord and recently had to make changes to it, had to upgrade the version of node and modules so that now it works when run with node app.js. however when I try to run the app with supervisord it fails with a node module error that was previously fixed by my upgrades. logged into my server as root, and also tried to make sure that user=root was set in the supervisord conf for the app but no change, not sure what the issue is.
